# Append text in GridView DataFields

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to append text in my ASP DataField:

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField='"https://media.expedia.com" + thumbNailUrl' HeaderText="Image" />
```

However, this is not working. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DataFormatString`

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="thumbNailUrl" DataFormatString="https://media.expedia.com/{0}" HeaderText="Image" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="thumbNailUrl" HeaderText="Image" />       

protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ea = e as GridViewRowEventArgs;
    if (ea.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var d = ea.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        var ob = d["thumbNailUrl"];
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(ob))
        {
            var cell = ea.Row.Cells[x];
            cell.Text = String.Format("https://media.expedia.com{0}", ob.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this as well, and let you know how this goes. To be fair the comment does resolve the issue.